# Python crash course 8-10

Tags: python

I'm currently reading Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes and doing some of the problem sets. One of them is giving me some difficulty and I was hoping someone could help me with it.

> 8-9. Magicians: Make a list of magician's names. Pass the list to a function called show_magicians(), which prints the name of each magician in the list.
>
> 8-10. Great Magicians: Start with a copy of your program from exercise 8-9. Write a function make_great() that modifies the list of magicians by adding the phrase *the great* to each magician's name. Call show_magicians() to see that the list has actually been modified.

And this is what I have for 8-9:

```
magician_names=['Alice', 'Alex', 'Blake']
def show_magicians(n):
    for magician in n:
        print (magician)

show_magicians(magician_names)
```

I just don't really know what to do for 8-10

Comment: To print, use either string concatenation `magician+=' the great'` or [.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) `print '{} the great'.format(magician)`. To *modify* the list, use a list comprehension: `magician_names=[e+' the great' for e in magician_names]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you can append to a string and reassign to add words to the end of each element:

```
magician += " the great"
```

Here, the `+=` operator appends a string, then reassigns, which is equivalent to the following:

```
magician = magician + " the great"
```

Now, you can add this to a function like so:

```
def make_great(list_magicians):
    for i in range(len(list_magicians)):
        list_magicians[i] += " the great"

make_great(magician_names)
show_magicians(magician_names)
```

The output is:

```
Alice the great
Alex the great
Blake the great
```

How this works is that we use a 'counter' for loop, similar to the ones in languages like C, (you can also use `enumerate` here), that loops through each element by using subscripts. Then it appends the string " the great" to all elements.

---

The reason why you cannot just do a simple `for-in` loop and modify those values is because `for-in` copies the value in the variable before `in`:

```
for magician in list_magicians: # magician is a temporary variable, does not hold actual reference to real elements
```

If they don't hold an actual reference, you cannot modify the reference, hence the reason you need to use counter loops to access the actual reference through subscript.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was the easiest for me to grasp. I don't think the book was looking for me to answer it like this but It works well an I get a better understanding of how the counter works. I was trying to figure that out last week for a homework assignment. Thanks again.

Comment: Downvoted because this is "homework" problem. Don't give away the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you already know how to iterate through the list. You want to make a similar function, where you modify the string referred to my `magician` to say, "the Great".

So, if you had a string "Smedley" and you wanted to change that to a string "Smedley the Great" how would you do it?

**update**

So now that the answer's been given away anyway, there are a couple of other options that are more "functional" and arguably safer since you're protected from aliasing etc.

Option 1: create a new list, eg: (These examples done with [iPython](https://ipython.org/) which is a very handy tool, worth installing for learning Python)

```
def make_great_1(lst):
    rtn = []
    for m in lst:
        rtn.append(m+" the Great")
    return rtn

In [7]: mages = [ 'Gandalf', 'Mickey' ]

In [8]: make_great_1(mages)
Out[8]: ['Gandalf the Great', 'Mickey the Great']
```

Option 2: use a list comprehension:

```
In [9]: [ mg+" the Great" for mg in mages ]
Out[9]: ['Gandalf the Great', 'Mickey the Great']
```

Now, the problem says to *modify* the list, and it's easy to imagine that means you should modify the strings, but in fact Python (unless you use a `MutableString`) just makes a copy anyway.  If you want to be really picky, either of these options could be re-done to assign the new list to `mages` in my case, or `magician_names` in yours.

Comment: right but when I do

 def make_great(original):
  for magician in original:
   magician+= ' the Great'

nothing happen.

Comment: @AlexMcClead This is because `for-in` loops copy the value into a temporary variable, not a direct reference to the list. Use either `enumerate` or `for-in range` to get index and subscript the list.

Comment: Or go functional and make a new list of new strings.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks you to modify `magician_names`. Since each entry in `magician_names` is a `str`, and `strs` are unmodifiable, you cannot simply modify each `str` in `magician_names` by appending `" the great"` to it. Instead, you need to *replace* each `str` in `magician_names` with its modified version.

So this seemingly straightforward approach:

```
def make_great(l):
    for name in l:
        name += " the great"

make_great(magician_names)
```

does not modify `magician_names`. It simply creates a new `str` object and assigns that to the `name` variable local to the `for loop`. Each element of `magician_names` is unchanged, i.e. it still points to the same `str` object.

But this approach:

```
def make_great(l):
    for index, name in enumerate(l):
        l[index] = name + " the great"

make_great(magician_names)
```

changes the `str` objects pointed to by `magician_names` and hence modifies `magician_names` as required.

---

To your comment,

```
for index, name in enumerate(l):
    l[index] = name + " the great"
```

is just the Pythonic way to write:

```
for index in range(len(l)):
    name = l[index]
    l[index] = name + " the great"
```

`enumerate(l)` returns an iterable (actually a lazy generator) that yields a matched `index, element` pair for each element in `l`.

Comment: I'm sure this is right, I just don't understand it yet. Index, name and enumerate(l) I don't understand yet.

Comment: @AlexMcClead `enumerate` just means go over all the elements at a given index with their value. `name` here is the value of the element, `index` is the index of the element.

Comment: @AlexMcClead  I just mentioned iPython. It's also a really nifty way of seeing what some expression means from an interpreter ("the REPL").

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I just started python a month ago. Hope this helps. Do correct me if i am wrong.

```
def show_magician(list):
for magician in list:
    print(magician.title())


def make_great(ori_magician_list, modified_magician_list):
while ori_magician_list:
    modified_magician = ori_magician_list.pop()
    modified_magician_list.append(modified_magician + ' the Great.')


magician_list = ['jack', 'john', 'jesse']
modified_list = []
make_great(magician_list, modified_list)
show_magician(modified_list)
```